# Snap to road combined with not snapped(GMaps v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got a some locations(In this case 4) in my database which i'm trying to show on a Map. What better way than Google maps, right? There is however one catch; Along with the location there's a "is_snapped" saved in my database which decided if the location is being snapped to with polylines.

Now i've made a function which is being looped through for each location out of my Db. Giving the marker(Latlng object) which has to be placed on the map and a snapped variable which is either 0 or 1(1 for snapped, 0 for not snapped).

Well, the basics of this function work. It doesn't snap where it doesn't need snapping and snaps where it has to be snapped. However; If it's snapped, it gives me two lines from A to B. One line that's snapped to the road, and another line not being snapped to the road. So somehow a duplicate object is pushed into my "path" array. But i can't seem to find the glitch in my function.

Can anyone check and see what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

```
function createLines(marker, snap) {
    if (!service) {
        service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    }

    if (snap != 0 && snap != 1) {
        snap = 0;
    }

    if (path.length > 0 && snap != 1) {
        path.push(marker);
    }

    if (path.length == 0) {
        path.push(marker);
        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map });
        poly.setPath(path);
    } else {
        service.route({
            origin: path[path.length - 1],
            destination: marker,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
        }, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                if(snap == 1) {
                    path = path.concat(result.routes[0].overview_path);
                }
                poly.setPath(path);
            }
        });
        distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
    }
    return Math.round(distance);
}
```

Note:The map is being created before this function so it's present and it shows me the markers in the right place. Just the polylines that screw up :-)

To get a feel of what's going on i included 3 pictures showing the combined snapped/unsnapped and seperated so you can see how it's supposed to be, sort of...

Here's the map with both the snapped lines as the non-snapped(As the code is made now)
http://www.envyum.nl/stupid_map.png

Here's the map with the snapped part left out (path = path.concat.....)
http://www.envyum.nl/stupid_map_wo_snap.png

And here's the map with the snapped parts in and unsnapped out(The path.push(marker))
http://www.envyum.nl/stupid_map_w_snap.png

For those interest, this is the function which calls the createLines function:

```
function drawMap(locations) {
    if(locations) {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i in locations) {
            loc = locations[i].latlng.split(', ');
            //Create a marker and give it a id(used later on to identify the correct inputfield)
            var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]);
            var mrkr = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerPos,
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                id: locations[i].tripId
            });

            //Create the lines between te markers
            createLines(markerPos, locations[i].is_snapped);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: at a guess, are you looping one time too many?

Comment: I think not. If i were the lines wouldn't duplicate every polyline...